# Is there an easy way to solve this real-world circle/congruent triangles/trigonometry problem?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, trigonometric-series

This is a real-world problem I've got to deal with, so help appreciated.  The diagram looks like this:

[image]
The diagram shows 4 congruent sectors of a circle radius ***r***, each of angle ***2A***, cut into triangles by chords length ***2d*** at the circumference.  The circle is shown in light grey, dotted. **OPX** and **PXT** are right angles, and **POT** < 90 degrees. The actual number of sectors ***n*** varies; ***n**=4* is just an example. It may be assumed 3 <= ***n*** <= 6, and that ***n***, ***d*** and ***h*** (all coloured blue) are given. ***A***, ***r*** and ***w*** are unknown.

Problem:  solve for ***r***.

Bonus points: solve for ***r*** in a way that's easy to use within Excel (where this ultimately needs to end up).......

The problem I have, relates to the fact that the actual number of sectors ***n*** is itself a parameter. I can't think of a way to solve it generally, that doesn't require some pretty horrific trigonometric identity expansions, possibly leading to some pretty nasty equations to simplify in *sin(A)* or *cos(A)*, and their sums and products.  That's a problem as I plan to use it within Excel, as part of a larger calculation spreadsheet.

It's trivial to solve with iteration, or programmatically, but because of the apparent presence of varying terms in *sin/cos A, sin/cos 2A, sin/cos 3A* etc, it's unclear if there is an elegant solution. Of course one can break all of those down using sin/cos addition formulae, but when "n" is itself a variable that's going to get incredibly messy in a spreadsheet calculation. Another way would be to hard code formulae for each of the 6 possible values of "n" and choose appropriately using `switch()` or `if()` logic. That's pretty horrible too. Because I'd still have to reduce the *sin/cos(A), sin/cos(2A)* etc terms by expansion, and then manually solve all 6 resulting equations, before writing the individual solutions into Excel.

The symmetry seems to be crying out for a totally different approach than obtaining a formula for the distances from ***PX*** to each of ***Q, R, S*** then finally ***T***, in terms of A, sin/cos A, sin/cos 2A, 3A, ..., then expanding all these, then solving formulaically...... and then finally, repeating that for each possible value of ***n***. But I can't think what other way there is, if any.

At a pinch I'll gladly take an Excel VBA solution, if thats best, because I can't think how to avoid the expansion of trig identities, either.  But perhaps I've missed a trick and there's an easier way? Even if not, perhaps there's more or less efficient ways to solve this, or it can be rewritten as a "well known" trigonometric series in *sin(1x), sin (2x), ..., sin(nx)*,  and perhaps some approach is amenable to simplifying enough to throw into Excel?

Comment: Related: [This diagrammatic answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1607308/409) to ["How can we sum up $\sin$ and $\cos$ series when the angles are in arithmetic progression?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/17966/409). It's not quite an exact duplicate, however.

Comment: Really useful answers there, with many approaches!!  Thank you?

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not mistaken, one has $\dfrac dr = \sin A$ and $\dfrac hd = \dfrac{2 \sin^2 nA}{\sin A}.$ Using multiple angles formulas, the righthandside can be expressed as a polynomial in variable $t=\sin A$.

So, solve the resulting polynomial equation to find the value of $t=\sin A$ and then $r=\dfrac{\sin A}{d}$ is what you're looking for.

Comment: You might also consider finding an approximate solution to the original equation involving $\sin(nA)$ and $\sin A$ by a numerical method, e.g. Newton-Raphson iteration.